# How to read a file that was just created by a function in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting blank line when I try to read the file that was just created by function above. When I run the same code in different file it is running just file. I see that file has been closed. But when I try to open and print. I am getting blank line.

I have copied the same code which I am trying to read to a different test file and run the code. I am read the file and print the lines and close the file.

```py
def running_symm_list_cmd():
    try:

        path_to_output_file = "symm_list_out.txt"
        myoutput = open(path_to_output_file, 'w')
        symm_list = "sudo symcfg list"
        Popen([symm_list], shell=True, stdout=myoutput, stderr=myoutput, universal_newlines=True)

    except OSError or ValueError as error_str:
        print(error_str)
        os.system(exit(2))
    finally:
        myoutput.close()
        print("checking if file is closed or not {}".format(myoutput.closed))


def getting_symm_list():

    try:
        print("INSIDE getting_symm_list TRY  function")
        symm_list = {}
        path = "/users/pjinde/scripts/symm_list_out.txt"
        symm_list_file = open(path, 'r')
        print("file mode is {m} and file name is {n}".format(m=symm_list_file.mode, n=symm_list_file.name))
        for line in symm_list_file.readlines():
            #print(line)
            symm_ids = re.search(r'(000197\d+)\s+\w+.*', line, re.M | re.I)
            if symm_ids:
                symm_list[symm_ids.group(1)] = None
                #print("Symmetrix id is {}".format(symm_ids.group(1)))

        for ids in symm_list.keys():
            print("symmetrix_id are {}".format(ids))

    except OSError as err:
        print("unable to get symm list due to error {}".format(err))
    finally:
        symm_list_file.close()
    return symm_list
```

I am expecting below output. Which tell that I was able to create a dictionary symm_list.

```
INSIDE getting_symm_list TRY  function
file mode is r and file name is /users/abcd/efcg/symm_list_out.txt
symmetrix_id are 00019780aaaa
symmetrix_id are 00019780aabc
symmetrix_id are 00019780aadd
symmetrix_id are 00019780aaee
symmetrix_id are 00019780aaff
symmetrix_id are 00019780aaeg
symmetrix_id are 00019790bbbb
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !!. thanks.

Comment: As Popen is running asymetrical, have you tried to wait for Popen to be done before closing file?
p = Popen(...)
p.wait()
Just a quick stab on it without mutch tought

Comment: I think you are right @Svavelsyra. I have used subprocess.call instead of Popen. I was planning to use Popen as I was planning to  execute shell commands by piping them. I change my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Popen was running asynchronously either I have use Popen.wait() till the sub process finishes. or we can use just subprocess.call

```py
def running_symm_list_cmd():
    try:

        path_to_output_file = "symm_list_out.txt"
        myoutput = open(path_to_output_file, 'w')
        symm_list = "sudo symcfg list"
        p1 = subprocess.call([symm_list], shell=True, stdout=myoutput, stderr=myoutput)

    except OSError or ValueError as error_str:
        print(error_str)
        os.system(exit(2))
    finally:
        myoutput.close()
        print("checking if file is closed or not {}".format(myoutput.closed))


def getting_symm_list():

    try:
        symm_list = {}
        path = "/users/pjinde/scripts/symm_list_out.txt"
        symm_list_file = open(path, 'r')
        #print("file mode is {m} and file name is {n}".format(m=symm_list_file.mode, n=symm_list_file.name))
        for line in symm_list_file.readlines():
            #print(line)
            symm_ids = re.search(r'(000197\d+)\s+\w+.*', line, re.M | re.I)
            if symm_ids:
                symm_list[symm_ids.group(1)] = None
                #print("Symmetrix id is {}".format(symm_ids.group(1)))

        for ids in symm_list.keys():
            print("symmetrix_id are {}".format(ids))

    except OSError as err:
        print("unable to get symm list due to error {}".format(err))
    finally:
        symm_list_file.close()
    return symm_list
```